# Not allowed to use ESC key for closing modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problems with making the modal window close with ESC key. I have this script:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a 
caption
var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
imgs[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  modalImg.src = e.target.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = e.target.alt;
});
}

 // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
 modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

I want to be allowed to close it not only by clicking the X button, but also with the ESC key. I am not really good at javascript so I will be really happy if you tell me what I should include in the code.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can call [onkeyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) on the entire document, check for ESC key, then set your modal display to none.

```
document.onkeyup = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // 27 is the ESC key
    if(e.keyCode === 27) modal.style.display = "none";
};
```

Comment: I should add it to the code that I provided? Or as a another paragraph?

Comment: Just add the code at the end of your example. You may also consider using document.addEventListener("keyup", function ...). Using document.onkeyup field may collide with existing code.

Comment: My page is simple image grid, so it's working perfectly now! Thank you very much!